# upload image then make it movable and resizable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make an image uploader, and after the upload, make it movable and resizable. I have 2 scripts with jquery, I can upload an image, and move/resize an other one, but can't use it together.

uploader:

```
<div class="upload">
<input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" /> <br>
</div>

<div class="block">
<div id="background">
<img id="bg" src="" alt="" width="auto" height="50%"/>
</div>
</div>

function readURL(input) {
if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (e) {
$('#bg')
.attr('src', e.target.result);
};
reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}
}
```

make another image resizable and movable:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(document).on('click', '.block-add', function () {
var a = $(this);
var src = a.find('img:first').attr('src');
var elem = $('<div class="container"><img src="' + src + '" class="blocks" /></div>');
$('.block').append(elem);
elem.draggable();
elem.find('.blocks:first').resizable();
return false;
});
});
```

It works separately but if I want to make it to an uploaded image, the image just doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the operation you wanna do is a little bit confusing.

first of all, decide what you are gonna do? If it was me I would use libraries like [Comman js](http://camanjs.com/) or [Pica resize image lib](https://github.com/nodeca/pica) for production use in order to store it on back-end too.

Comment: I don't really want to use anything else, just jquery. I've figured out, that i can make it draggable with `$( function() { $( "#bg" ).draggable();  } );` but `  $( function() {
    $( "#bg" ).resizable();
  } );` messes up something and I can't even see the uploaded image, if I use this function.